# Clever integral and formula

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Find $$\int \sin(2020x)\sin^{2018} (x) dx$$
and use it to derive a general formula.

Comment: Welcome to Math.stack. You should show your attempts on the solution to your exercises, so that users will be willing to help you :)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sin%282020+x%29+sin%5E%282018%29%28x%29+dx.

Comment: Ok yes thank you. Still learning how things go here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sin%282020+x%29+sin%5E%282018%29%28x%29+dx

To elaborate: let
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin^{2k+1}(x) \sin((2k+1)x)}{2k+1}$$
Then,
$$\begin{aligned}
f'(x)&=\frac{(2k+1)\sin^{2k}(x)\cos(x) \sin((2k+1)x) + (2k+1)\sin^{2k+1}(x) \cos((2k+1)x)}{2k+1}\\
&=\sin^{2k}(x)\Big(\cos(x) \sin((2k+1)x) + \sin(x) \cos((2k+1)x)\Big)\\
&=\sin^{2k}(x)\Big(\sin((2k+2)x)\Big)
\end{aligned}$$
Where the third equality follows from: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Algebra/SineInRhombus.shtml